# Error PHP variable indefinida

Tags: php, xampp

Hola buenas estoy haciendo un ejercicio en php y tengo el problema de que no ser como solucionar el siguiente error:
**Warning: Undefined array key "productes" in C:\XAMPP APP\htdocs\PHP\intro\ex9\factura.php on line 53**

**Warning: foreach() argument must be of type array|object, null given in C:\XAMPP APP\htdocs\PHP\intro\ex9\factura.php on line 53**

El ejercicio trata de hacer un carro de la compra donde se vayan añadiendo productos y se vayan guardando en una sesión. Se tendra que mostrar los productos guardados en una página aparte con la suma total y los productos con su cantidad, nombre i código
Aqui estaria el codigo donde me aparece el error:

```
<?php
    session_start();


    if(isset($_SESSION['comanda'])){
        $comanda = $_SESSION['comanda'];
        $missatge = 'Comanda rebuda!';
    }
    else{
        $comanda = ['productes'=>[]];
        $missatge = 'No hi ha comanda!';
    }
?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Factura</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h2>Factura total</h2>
    <p><?php echo $missatge?></p>
    <?php if (!empty($comanda['productes'])): ?>
    <table>
        <tr>
            <th>Producte</th>
            <th>Preu</th>
            <th>Quantitat</th>
        </tr>
        <?php
        foreach ($comanda['productes'] as $codi_producte => $detalls_producte) {
            echo '<tr>';
            echo '<td>' . $detalls_producte['nom'] . '</td>';
            echo '<td>$' . $detalls_producte['preu'] . '</td>';
            echo '<td>' . $detalls_producte['quantitat'] . '</td>';
            echo '</tr>';
        }
        ?>
    </table>
    <?php endif; ?>
    <p>Total de la comanda: <?php echo number_format(calcularTotal($comanda), 2) . ' €'; ?></p>
    <a href="carrocompra.php">Afegir més coses</a>
    <br>
    <br>
    <a href="tancar_sessio.php">Tanca la sessió</a>
</body>
</html>


<?php
    //Funció per calcular el total de la comanda
function calcularTotal($comanda) {
    $total = 0;

    foreach ($comanda['productes'] as $producte) {
        $total += $producte['preu'] * $producte['quantitat'];
    }

    return $total;
}
?>



</body>
</html>
```

Y a continuación tendria la pagina de donde provienen los productos del carrito de compra:

```
<?php
    session_start();

    if(!isset($_SESSION['productes'])){
        $_SESSION['productes']=[
            ['codi'=>'0001', 'nom'=>'Oli de oliva 1L', 'preu'=>10,90],
            ['codi'=>'0002', 'nom'=>'Empanada', 'preu'=>3.30],
            ['codi'=>'0003', 'nom'=>'Dotzena de ous', 'preu'=>8,50],
            ['codi'=>'0004', 'nom'=>'Llet', 'preu'=>4,60],
            ['codi'=>'0005', 'nom'=>'Tomàtiga', 'preu'=>3.99],
            ['codi'=>'0006', 'nom'=>'Ginjols', 'preu'=>4.30],
        ];
    }


    if(!isset($_SESSION['comanda'])){
        $_SESSION['comanda'] = [];
    }

    if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']==='POST'){
        $_SESSION['comanda']['correu']=$_POST['correu'];

        foreach($_SESSION['productes'] as $producte){
            $codi_producte=$producte['codi'];
            $quantitat=$_POST['quantitat'.$codi_producte];

            if($quantitat>0){
                $_SESSION['comanda']['productes'][$codi_producte] =
                [
                    'nom'=>$producte['nom'],
                    'preu'=> $producte['preu'],
                    'quantitat'=>$quantitat,
                ];
            }
        }
        header('Location:factura.php');
        exit;
    }    


?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Carro de sa compra</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h2>Carrito de sa compra</h2>
    <form action="#" method="$_POST" >
    <h3>Correu Electrónic</h3>
    <input type="text" name="email" required >
    <table>
            <tr>
                <th>Producte</th>
                <th>Preu</th>
                <th>Quantitat</th>
            </tr>
            <?php
                foreach ($_SESSION['productes'] as $producte) {
                    $codi_producte = $producte['codi'];
                    $quantitat = isset($_SESSION['comanda']['productes'][$codi_producte]['quantitat']) ? $_SESSION['comanda']['productes'][$codi_producte]['quantitat'] : 0;
                    echo '<tr>';
                    echo '<td>' . $producte['nom'] . '</td>';
                    echo '<td>' . $producte['preu'] . '€'.'</td>';
                    echo '<td><input type="text" name="quantitat_' . $codi_producte . '" value="' . $quantitat . '"></td>';
                    echo '</tr>';
                }
            ?>
        </table>
    <br>
    <br>
    <a href="factura.php">Confirmar Comanda</a>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: en la linea donde haces la llamada a la función `calcularTotal`, no tienes asegurado que el array que pasas tenga el indice `productes`. puedes poner un if dentro de la función que analice si existe ese indice y asi hacer el calculo, o si no existe que devuelva 0 (por ej)

Comment: Claro pero esto solo es preventivo para que no salga el error, me ha servido y te doy las gracias. Ahora solo me falta saber porque no me encuentra definida la variable. Le he estado dando vueltas y no veo nada.

Comment: Nota que `isset()` es verdadero con un arreglo vacío (`[]`). Considera combinarlo con [`empty()`](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.empty.php) o inicializar con `null`.

Answer (score 0):

Es importante hacer los correctos controles de de datos, si esta linea que veo en el primer codigo es tal cual:

```
<?php if (!empty($comanda['productes'])): ?>
```

es normal que te de error, por que le tas preguntando al nodo `productes` si es un `array` vacio, sin saber si existe el nodo.

lo correcto seria hacer esto:

```
<?php if (isset($comanda['productes'])) && !empty($comanda['productes'])): ?>
```

Esto validara con [`isset()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.isset.php) que la variable + nodo esten declaradas. si no existe el nodo, nisiquiera continuara la validacion de si esta vacio, nunca confies de que un nodo existe en un array comprueba y valida siempre...